AWS VPC Interface Endpoint Security Group Best Practice
I am creating a VPC Interface Endpoint to a couple of aws services (logs and ecr) to keep traffic internal to aws for both cost saving and security reasons. I am wondering what the best practice is for the security group attached to the Endpoint. I am adding the endpoint specifically for my ECS Task (a standard rest api) but the endpoint effects all the services in my VPC such as lambdas or ec2 instances.
Here is my pulumi for the creation of the endpoint and I have added comments with the two options I am considering. Is there any security risk or other problem with allowing all traffic in the VPC access to the endpoint? Is it better to give each security group access? I would prefer to just allow the whole VPC's Cidr because that would make deployment and management much easier.
const vpcEndpointSecurityGroup = new aws.ec2.SecurityGroup(`sg`, {
    vpcId: vpcId
});

new aws.ec2.SecurityGroupRule(`vpc-endpoint-sg-egress`, {
    securityGroupId: vpcEndpointSecurityGroup.id,
    fromPort: 0,
    toPort: 65535,
    protocol: "tcp",
    type: "egress",
    cidrBlocks: ["0.0.0.0/0"]
});

new aws.ec2.SecurityGroupRule(`vpc-endpoint-sg-ingress`, {
    securityGroupId: vpcEndpointSecurityGroup.id,
    fromPort: 443,
    toPort: 443,
    protocol: "tcp",
    type: "ingress",
    cidrBlocks: vpcCidrBlock //Is this okay?
    sourceSecurityGroupId: ecsTaskSecurityGroup //or do I need to do one of these for each of my services?
});

return new aws.ec2.VpcEndpoint(`vpc-endpoint-logs`, {
    vpcId: vpcId,
    serviceName: `com.amazonaws.${region}.logs`,
    vpcEndpointType: "Interface",
    securityGroupIds: [vpcEndpointSecurityGroup.id],
    subnetIds: vpcPrivateSubnetIds,
    privateDnsEnabled: true,
});


The VPC endpoint is lower latency and higher bandwidth than public endpoints. It may be slightly more secure as the network traffic is more direct, though TLS means the public endpoint is sufficiently secure. In my opinion everything in the VPC should use the VPC Endpoint. I wouldn't restrict VPC endpoint access.
The VPC endpoint creates private DNS entries that override the public DNS endpoint entries. You would probably have trouble reaching the public endpoints in a VPC where the endpoints are deployed. More info here.
